# How to set lining numbers in math in Beamer (with EB Garamond) under XeLaTeX

Tags: beamer, math-mode, xetex, fontspec, oldstylenums

I'm using EB Garamond with XeLaTeX and Beamer as follows.  (I'm not actually sure whether it's all necessary--advice accepted.):

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  % not sure why
\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign} % use URW Garamond rather than Computer Modern in math when EB Garamond is missing a character
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text} % not sure why
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{EB Garamond}
```

(I previously loaded EB Garamond as a system font on a Mac using its Font book app.)

EB Garamond uses oldstyle numbers by default.  I can easily change to lining numbers in regular text by various means, e.g. by inserting this at the top of the document: `\addfontfeatures{Numbers=Lining}`.  However, none of the methods I've tried has any effect on math in `$$`, `\[\]`, etc.; the oldstyle numbers remain.  This is a Beamer issue--the problem doesn't occur with the article class.

How can I switch to lining numbers in math mode (without resorting to `\mbox`)?  A full minimal working example is below.

Thanks!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{EB Garamond}

\usefonttheme{serif}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
text (default, oldstyle): 1234567890\\
\addfontfeatures{Numbers=Lining}
text (lining): 1234567890\\
math (why is this oldstyle?): $1234567890$
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you meaning `beamer` rather than `article`? I don't think it's a good idea to use Garamond for a presentation.

Comment: Thanks egreg.  Yes, the class was `beamer`.  Not sure how that typo got into the MWE--won't run with `article`.  I just fixed it.  (I'm not someone in the "presentations must be in san serif" camp.  For me a Garamond is a good choice for presentations; I've given it quite a bit of thought, and have worked up a Beamer class that I like.)

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution.  It's easy, it's obvious, and though it's not a complete solution, it's good enough for me.  The solution is to move`Numbers=Lining` from `\addfontfeatures` to `defaultfontfeatures`, like this:

```
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text, Numbers=Lining}
```

By making lining numbers the default, they penetrate into math mode.  (I should have tried that first, but I didn't fully understand what I had in my preamble--I just knew that it worked, apart from the oldstyle/lining problem.)

This isn't a complete solution because it affects math mode throughout the document. I still don't know how to switch back and forth between lining and oldstyle numbers in math mode.  Adding additional calls to `\addfontfeature` or `\defaultfontfeature` in the document have no effect on math mode.  However, using lining numbers everywhere is what I wanted, anyway.